# python pandas ExcelWriter issue while formatting cells as text

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I have a requirement to color my excel sheet column which is written from a pandas dataframe.

Here is a sample I will give and explain the problem I am facing.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['A2','B18'],data=[[10,123415209123456789],[12,1223152012345678088],[10,1234152091234566666],[12,1223152012345678777]],dtype='object')
print(df)

   A2                  B18
0  10   123415209123456789
1  12  1223152012345678088
2  10  1234152091234566666
3  12  1223152012345678777

print(df.info)

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 2 columns):
#   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
0   A2      4 non-null      object
1   B18     4 non-null      object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 192.0+ bytes
None
```

I do have some complex formatting requirements to color, align not only the data but also the header. And thats the reason I thought of using the excelwriter rather than pandas styler.

But there, I am facing an issue with text formatting

```
#Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(dataFolder + 'tmp_12_test126.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet1',index=False)

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book

col_format=[{},{'bg_color': 'cyan', 'num_format': '@'}]

# Start iterating through the columns and the rows to apply the format
for col in range(df.shape[1]):
    for row in range(df.shape[0]):
        if len(col_format[col]) > 0 :
           worksheet.write(row+1,col,df.iloc[row,col],workbook.add_format(col_format[col]))

# Finally write the file
writer.save()
```

But this writes the B18 column converting it into a scientific notation and causing the lose of last 4 digits value.

Can any one help what am I doing wrong ?
I read through and found that 'num_format': '@' is what is required to force the cell to a text formatting.
But for some reason it is not working.

Comment: When I tried your dataframe as given, and `df.to_excel()`, I get a number in scientific format. If I format this as 'Number' in Excel, the last few digits become zeroes. This is what I would expect as Excel stores numbers as doubles, so it loses precision. So I don't quite understand the statement: "Basically if I write this df to excel using a df.to_excel() with out excelwriter ,it writes the data correctly as 18 bytes text for B18 column and do not lose any digits" as I get a different result. Are you creating the numbers as strings in your dataframe initially?

Comment: You are right. I will modify the qn. Originally I was getting the df from a pandas read_sql and when I write trough df.To_excel, it was working fine. For illustration , I created a df manually with object data and that also has the same problem.

Comment: If you want to display all the digits exactly, then you will have to pass to Excel as a string, not a number. As a test, try typing the number into a cell in Excel, and see what happens: the last few digits become zeroes. Once you have passed numbers you will lose the precision, even if you change the display format.

Comment: Yes, keeping that in mind only, I had converted the pandas dataframe column to an object. So, technically speaking, pandas passing the field as a string to excel. So, why it is still taking it as number ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dtype=object` does not convert numbers to strings. Instead it tries to coerce each value into the most appropriate python type. If you want strings instead of numbers, you can either make the default type `dtype=str` (which coerces all columns) or choose a different type for each column using `astype()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.DataFrame(columns=['A2','B18'],
                 data=[[10,123415209123456789],
                       [12,1223152012345678088],
                       [10,1234152091234566666],
                       [12,1223152012345678777]],
                 dtype=object)

print('df1 types:')
[print(idx,type(val[0]),type(val[1])) for idx,val in df1.iterrows()]

df2=pd.DataFrame(columns=['A2','B18'],
                 data=[[10,123415209123456789],
                       [12,1223152012345678088],
                       [10,1234152091234566666],
                       [12,1223152012345678777]],
                 dtype=str)

print('df2 types:')
[print(idx,type(val[0]),type(val[1])) for idx,val in df2.iterrows()]

df3=pd.DataFrame(columns=['A2','B18'],
                 data=[[10,123415209123456789],
                       [12,1223152012345678088],
                       [10,1234152091234566666],
                       [12,1223152012345678777]]).astype({'A2': int, 'B18':str})

print('df3 types:')
[print(idx,type(val[0]),type(val[1])) for idx,val in df3.iterrows()]
```

Output:

```
df1 types:
0 <class 'int'> <class 'int'>
1 <class 'int'> <class 'int'>
2 <class 'int'> <class 'int'>
3 <class 'int'> <class 'int'>
df2 types:
0 <class 'str'> <class 'str'>
1 <class 'str'> <class 'str'>
2 <class 'str'> <class 'str'>
3 <class 'str'> <class 'str'>
df3 types:
0 <class 'int'> <class 'str'>
1 <class 'int'> <class 'str'>
2 <class 'int'> <class 'str'>
3 <class 'int'> <class 'str'>
```

Comment: Converting the dataframe to str did the trick. And this is a new knowledge to me. Thnx a lot.